is that possible to estimate record bag size from topic hz and msg defines (ros2)?
as titled, assume i have follow topics to ros2 bag record:
topic_foo at 10Hz with MsgFoo.msg defined as：
# MsgFoo.msg
uint8 signal_a
float32 signal_b
uint32[] signal_c # estimated max size could be 100
uint64[4] signal_d

topic_bar at 100Hz with MsgBar.msg defined as:
# MsgBar.msg
MsgFoo[2] signal_e
uint8 signal_f

is that possible to estimated the size of the recorded bags (e.g. 10Mb for 10min) or data traffic (10Mb/sec)? is there any docs or equations for this? thanks so much

I guess you cannot do it but you can specify the max size, in terms of bytes, for a ROS 2 bag with the flag -b. After reaching the specified size a new bag will be created.
  -b MAX_BAG_SIZE, --max-bag-size MAX_BAG_SIZE
                        maximum size in bytes before the bagfile will be split. Default it is
                        zero, recording written in single bagfile and splitting is disabled.


In the file metadata.yaml (created by the record command) there is an entry called message_count, you can compare this value with the size of the recorded bag.

thanks, i think this test could be done for evaluation/assessment bag size, however i wish to find a way just by theoretical estimation/calculation. thanks anyway
